# AS3 reference error using custom event

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

****EDIT - I find what is giving me the error is when i try to change the graphics properties of the movieclip.****

I am receiving this error. "ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property item not found on flash.events.MouseEvent and there is no default value. at PlayScreen/onClick()".
I did a bit of research and most sites say it is due to a typo. but as far as i can tell it looks fine?

I have two events which are set out exactly the same as far as i can tell. One is triggered onclick and the other onhover. The hover event works fine but when i use the onclick event i recieve the error above. However even though i receive the error the function still works as it should.

Here is my code.
the code below creates a new Grid. then the custom events are added. the hover event works fine with no errors. the onclick event works fine but i get the error.

```
package  {
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class PlayScreen extends MovieClip {
    public var grid:Grid;

    public function PlayScreen() {
        grid = new Grid();
        grid.addEventListener( GridEvent.HOVER, onHover);
        grid.addEventListener( GridEvent.TILECLICK, onClick);
        grid.x = 0;
        grid.y = 0;
        addChild( grid );

    }

    public function onHover(event:*){
        event.item.graphics.beginFill(0x66ff66);
        event.item.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x22ff22);
        event.item.graphics.drawRect(-30*0.5, -30*0.5, 30, 30);
        event.item.graphics.endFill();

    }

    public function onClick(event:*){
        event.item.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        event.item.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x22ff22);
        event.item.graphics.drawRect(-30*0.5, -30*0.5, 30, 30);
        event.item.graphics.endFill();
    }
```

Below is my grid class. It contains a movieclip which has two mouseEvents added to it which then trigger the custom events.

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Grid extends MovieClip {

    public function Grid() {
        var test = new MovieClip();
        test.x = 0;
        test.y = 0;
        test.graphics.beginFill(0x66ff66); 
        test.graphics.drawRect(-tileWidth*0.5, -tileHeight*0.5, tileWidth, tileHeight);
        test.graphics.endFill();
        test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overTile);
        test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickTile);
        addChild(test);
    }

    function overTile (event:*) {
        dispatchEvent( new GridEvent( GridEvent.HOVER, event.target) );
    }

    function clickTile(event:*) {
        dispatchEvent( new GridEvent( GridEvent.TILECLICK, event.target) );
    }

}
```

Below are my custom events

```
   package  
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class GridEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const HOVER :String = "hover";
        public static const TILECLICK :String = "click";
        public var item;

        public function GridEvent (type:String, item)
        {
                this.item = item;
                super(type);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your full source code? There's no reason why Flash would give an error about MouseEvent when you are not even giving a type to the event. There must be some other issue going on.

Comment: It is not all the code because the full code is quite extensive. However i get the same issue with this. 
I Find that it is when i try to change the graphics properties. If i dont do that i dont get an error. So i dont understand why it gives me an error for the onclick function but not the hover function?. Thankyou for your reply too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving the `event` and the `item` a type.
use `Sprite` instead of `MovieClip`.

and another thing i didn't implement - would be best if you created a custom Tile-class for your tiles then you could set the type of the item in your GridEvent as Tile and not as Sprite/MovieClip.

this should work ....

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class PlayScreen extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var grid:Grid;

        public function PlayScreen() 
        {
            grid = new Grid();
            grid.addEventListener( GridEvent.HOVER, onHover);
            grid.addEventListener( GridEvent.TILECLICK, onClick);
            grid.x = 0;
            grid.y = 0;
            addChild( grid );

        }

        private function onHover(event:GridEvent):void
        {
            if (event.item != null)
            {
                var g:Graphics = event.item.graphics;
                g.beginFill(0x66ff66);
                g.lineStyle(2, 0x22ff22);
                g.drawRect(-30*0.5, -30*0.5, 30, 30);
                g.endFill();
            }
        }

        private function onClick(event:GridEvent):void
        {
            if (event.item != null)
            {
                var g:Graphics = event.item.graphics;
                g.beginFill(0x000000);
                g.lineStyle(2, 0x22ff22);
                g.drawRect(-30*0.5, -30*0.5, 30, 30);
                g.endFill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Grid extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Grid() 
        {
            var test = new Sprite();
            test.x = 0;
            test.y = 0;
            test.graphics.beginFill(0x66ff66); 
            test.graphics.drawRect(-tileWidth*0.5, -tileHeight*0.5, tileWidth, tileHeight);
            test.graphics.endFill();
            test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overTile);
            test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickTile);
            addChild(test);

            test.mouseChildren = false;
        }

        private function overTile (event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (event.cancelable)
            {
                // stop MouseEvent from bubbling
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
            dispatchEvent( new GridEvent( GridEvent.HOVER, event.target) );
        }

        private function clickTile(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (event.cancelable)
            {
                // stop MouseEvent from bubbling
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
            dispatchEvent( new GridEvent( GridEvent.TILECLICK, event.target) );
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class GridEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const HOVER :String = "hover";
        public static const TILECLICK :String = "click";
        public var item:Sprite;

        public function GridEvent (type:String, item:Sprite)
        {
                this.item = item;
                super(type);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou this has solved my issue! your examples are great and i will be creating a tile class :).